# Calendar Events Entry Similar to Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Anyone know of a good calendar event entry setup similar to Google calendar?  Looking for a plugin for one of the major javascript frameworks. Preferably jQuery.

Here is what Google is doing and looking for something similar...

[image: Google Calendar - Event Repeat]

[image: Google Calendar - Event Setup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you'll do at this point is probably [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

[image: fullcalendar screenshot]

> DISCLAIMER: FullCalendar is great for displaying events, but it isn't a complete solution for event content-management. Beyond dragging an event to a different time/day, you cannot change an event's name or other associated data. It is up to you to add this functionality through FullCalendar's event hooks.